# Stage final after fail the pipeline-jenkins

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline-jenkins also I use a jenkinsfile with several stage, How can I do If in a stage the pipeline fail after that a stage is exacuted? For instance to stop and remove several docker container.

Thanks

Comment: Good maner man, you downvote but you do not write any comment

Comment: Given the accepted answer, I assume this is about the script style jenkinsfile, not declarative groovy file? If so could you please specify in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try/catch to get the error, finally block to do the "final" stage ?

```
try {
  stage name: "something": 
} catch (err) {
  // handle errors here ? 
} finally {
  stage name: "cleanup"
}
```